# Excel formula to return the number of occurrence of a string in a column

Tags: excel-2010

I have a Column "Name" as follows and I would like to find the occurrence of a value in the same column in the adjacent Column "Occurrence" as follows: Column "Occurrence" should show the Occurrence of the String next to it till that row

```
Name   Occurrence
Alpha   1
Bravo   1
Alpha   2
Alpha   3
Charlie 1
Charlie 2
Golf    1
Golf    2
Golf    3
Hotel   1
```

I tried solving this but couldn't succeed, is there is a way to write a formula in column "Occurrence"?

Comment: Consider using ***COUNTIF()***

Comment: Might want to check out the countif formula in excel. This might be a better question for the superuser site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formulas can be fixed or mutable, or mixed, which is what you want.
The formula should reference the start of the list as a fixed point, but have the end of the list as changable. The $sign is used to tell Excel that a formula used a fixed reference, which will not change when you copy or fill the formula to other cells.

If Name is cell A1 and Occurrence is cell B1

B1 formula = `COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)`

Drag formula down.

The start of the list, $A$2, will stay the same as you copy the formula down. The other two parts will change the row number.